# Mongo DB query issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I am beginner in Mongo DB. I wrote the query see below for your further reference.

My Query is

```
$result =  $this->likes->find(array("post_id" => $post_id));
```

In that my table name is "likes" having the field name `post_id`, I am passing the `$post_id` (its my dynamic value example `$post_id= "55b86fb60fdd9419128b4567"`).

But I cannot get my expected result from the below query, if I pass the `$post_id` is static means I got it my desired result.

Thanks advance for your help

Comment: What is the desired result and what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

> You are attempting to use a string to match a `MongoId`. Keep in mind that these are two different datatypes. This is there in [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php)

You should query like following:

```
$result =  $this->likes->find(array("post_id" => new MongoId($post_id)));
```

As explained in [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php), You can print query result by using -

```
foreach ($result as $doc) {
  var_dump($doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$result =  $this->likes->find(array("post_id" => new MongoId($post_id)));
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for your reply. how to print this query like mysql.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing to be done with MySQL, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Try This:

```
function connection($tableName){        
    // Connect to Mongo
    //$this->connection = new MongoClient('localhost:27017'); //for linux
    $this->connection = new Mongo('localhost:27017'); // for window

    // Select a database
    $this->db = $this->connection->databaseName;

    // Select a collection
    $this->posts = $this->db->$tableName;
}

$this->connection('likes'); // likes is collection name
$id= "55b86fb60fdd9419128b4567";
$members = $this->posts->find(array("post_id" => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$result =  $this->likes->find(array("post_id" => new\ MongoId($post_id)));